# C# Rabbitmq serialize message and desiralize original type

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using Rabbitmq client to produce and consume messages. My messages is like this.

```
public interface IMessage{}

public class PlaceOrder: IMessage{ 
  public string id{ get; set; }
}
```

I have two c# console applicaiton projects. One of them **Producer** and other is **Consumer**.

### Producer console applicaiton

```
public class Producer{
    public void Save(IMessage message){
        ....
        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        ....
        // append queue serializedObject 
    }
}
```

### Consumer console applicaiton

```
public class Consumer{
    public void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, IBasicProperties properties, byte[] body){
        ....
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body));
        ....

    }
}
```

Here `message` type is Object. And consumer console applicaiton does not knows **PlaceOrder** type. It only knows IMessage interface type. How can I cast or convert original type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the options in NewtonSoft.Json's [TypeNameHandling enumeration](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm).  Set this on a [JsonSerializerSettings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) and pass it into your calls to `De/SerializeObject()`.

You may also want to evaluate [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/), which is specifically geared to this approach out-of-box, and adds other functionality.

Note there can be some disadvantages (architecturally) to insisting that message producers and consumers always use identically-named types with identical message structures.  You can end up tightly coupling all producers and consumers, such that all must be deployed in lock-step when a message format changes (as opposed to adopting a [Tolerant Reader](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html) approach, which can allow for more loosely-coupled evolution of producers and consumers).  Depends on your project goals, but an aspect to consider.